# Android - Activity recreate after open Camera App on Xiaomi

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera

I'm facing a problem is my Activity has been recreated after open Camera app.

This is my flow:

- Using the app
- Press Home button to put app into background
- Open Camera app default in device
- Re-open my app -> My Activity has been recreated and lost all data
  (issue)

How to prevent re-creating Activity or resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you've saved the state of your activity, then you wouldn't lose any data, even if your process is killed and recreated due to low memory.

Comment: Thank @ianhanniballake for response. I'm put data in ViewModel. How to keep ViewModel in this case?

Comment: ViewModels aren't kept over process death and recreation - you'd need to use saved instance state, storing the minimal set of information in order to recreate your data from disk (ala, a local database / file based cache). You'd need to include your code and what you're expecting to save/restore to get more detailed help.

Comment: The origin of the problem is the opening of the Camera app. It makes my Activity recreated. Can prevent it?

Comment: You can't prevent the device running out of memory. You have to handle process death and recreation.

Comment: I agree with this. I want to talk about the case open Camera app, like in my flow above.